# chainerのConvolution2Dの引数

Tags: python, chainer, 機械学習

chainerのConvolution2Dの引数について質問です。
example/imagenet/nin.pyに定義されている

```
mlpconv1=L.MLPConvolution2D(
    3, (96, 96, 96), 11, stride=4, wscale=w),
mlpconv2=L.MLPConvolution2D(
    96, (256, 256, 256), 5, pad=2, wscale=w),
mlpconv3=L.MLPConvolution2D(
    256, (384, 384, 384), 3, pad=1, wscale=w),
mlpconv4=L.MLPConvolution2D(
    384, (1024, 1024, 1000), 3, pad=1, wscale=w),
```

というネットワーク構造ですが、2つ目の引数の配列は何者でしょうか。
また最後のwscaleとは何でしょうか。

一つ目は入力チャネル数、3つ目は畳み込む大きさ、4つ目はパディングの数なのはわかります。
公式のdocumentには出力チャネル数と書いてありましたが、それがなぜ配列なのでしょうか。

ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

そちらはConvolution2DではなくMLPConvolution2Dですので、拡張されています。

http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/_modules/chainer/links/connection/mlp_convolution_2d.html

wscaleは重みのランダムに初期値を決める際のパラメータです。